# missed link between "step jobs" and jobs in job network definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have configured a batch that run every step as separate jobs by using what is described in the reference manual.
This kind of approach is very useful because I can start the single batch directly as a single Job or as part of a more complex job that we can call "job network".
for example I have a `mainNetJob`:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml" />
<job id="mainNetJob"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"  restartable="true" incrementer="incrementer">
    <step id="mainNetJob.closeconnections" next="mainNetJob.userLogout" >
        <job ref = "closeconn" job-launcher="syncJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
    </step>        
     <step id="mainNetJob.userLogout" next="mainNetJob.postReminder">
        <job ref = "userLogoutJob" job-launcher="syncJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
     </step>    
     <step id="mainNetJob.postReminder" next="mainNetJob.checkMails">
        <job ref = "postReminderJob" job-launcher="syncJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
     </step>             
     <step id="mainNetJob.checkMails" >
        <job ref = "checkMailsJob" job-launcher="syncJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="jobParametersExtractor"/>
     </step>
</job>
```

Then I can define (even in separate XML saved in the folder `META-INF/spring/batch/jobs`) for each single Job.

For example and once for all, in `closeconn.xml` I have defined:

```
<job id = "closeconn" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable="true" incrementer="incrementer">
     <step id="closeconnStepInitUpd" next="closeconn1">
        <tasklet ref="closeconnInitUpd"/>
    </step>        
    <step id="closeconn1" next="closeconn2" >
        <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="closeconnReader1" writer="closeconnWriter"
                   commit-interval="5" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
     <step id="closeconn2" >
        <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="closeconnReader2" writer="closeconnWriter"   
                   commit-interval="5" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
 </job>
```

If I run each Job with `job-launcher="syncJobLauncher"`, each step will be executed only when previous is finished with an "asycJobLouncher" I can decide to execute some or all step together.
This is very nice and is 100% working!

The only problem is: when I get a look in `Spring-batch-admin-console` for Job execution, in the `mainNetJob` I can only see the steps of `mainNetJob` and I have NO WAY to navigate to the real Job (i.e. `closeconn`).

Why I need to navigate to the "real" job ?

Let us suppose the `closeconn` job read 1000 records if you look in the console at the `mainNetJob.closeconnections` Step I always shows 0 record read, 0 write, ... which is a useless information.

I get a look to modify the console but I soon realize that I have no information on DB to link a step of a "network" job to the "real" job. To patch this for a while, I changed the `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` by adding a column `FROM_BSE_ID` ( that is "from batch step execution") with the meaning of the ID of the Step that started the execution of this job.

This obviously had required to change a lot of class in batch core to let the id of the job to be written in the `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.FROM_BSE_ID`.
This because I can get the ID of the step-job only when I am in the `JobStep.doExecute` method and need put it in the `jobExecution` instance class "BEFORE" it will be persisted.
Unfortunately the persistence of `jobExecution` is done by `jobLauncher` by calling the job-repository ( I found it in `SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution`).
The only way I found to pass the `stepJobID` from the `JobStep` class to `SimpleJobRepository` class is to pass it as a `JobParameter`. This solution works, but is disgusting me.

I don't know if I explained this issue well, but I hope so.
Could somebody suggest me something better to realize that link between step job and jobs?
Is this a change in the way String Batch jobs works that could interest somebody else?

Thank you,
Franco